# Where to edit the template that is generating the code for dynamic_sidebar left-sidebar in the Understrap theme?

Tags: php, theme-development, child-theme

### Question

where can I edit the template for the sidebar? My question is if the `dynamic_sidebar` pulls in from another template that I can find either in the main wordpress files, the theme, or if it just pulls only the widget. And what would be the workflow to best address this.

### Background

Created a child theme based on [Understrap](https://understrap.com/)

In my `left-sidebarpage.php` there is a line for the sidebar

```
<?php get_sidebar( 'left' ); ?>
```

But where do i edit that? The php page that I looked in was `sidebar-left.php` but that has nothing I can edit, just a loop

```
<?php if ( 'both' === $sidebar_pos ) : ?>
<div class="col-md-2 widget-area" id="left-sidebar" role="complementary">
    <?php else : ?>
<div class="col-md-3 widget-area" id="left-sidebar" role="complementary">
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php dynamic_sidebar( 'left-sidebar' ); ?>
```

That final line,

```
<?php dynamic_sidebar( 'left-sidebar' ); ?>
```

what is it pulling from and where can i edit that code so i can give it classes? i can see that it pulls in menu items that were added in the menu from dashboard in **appearance > menus**

Comment: look into the functions files of the theme, and look for the codes with `register_sidebar()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dynamic_sidebar pulls whatever widgets are assigned to that sidebar.  If you want to add a class for the whole sidebar, surround the call in a div that you can then assign classes.

```
<?php if ( is_active_sidebar( 'left-sidebar' ) ) : ?>
    <div class="sideclass">
        <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'left-sidebar' ); ?>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: My question is if the `dynamic_sidebar` pulls in from another template that I can find either in the main wordpress files, the theme, or if it just pulls only the widget. for example in a project that I am maintaining, there is a `<ul>` with classname of the menu that was named in the dashboard for plugins.

Comment: That's from the widget

Comment: Ok I am going to accept your answer, and edit my question to reflect what I should have asked. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Thanks.  If you can give details of what you are trying to do I'll try to help more.

Comment: I actually found a workaround yesterday, by targeting the class of the `<ul>` being generated in the sidebar menu. Initially when I posted the question I was just confused by where the menu was being generated from, i was going to add a class to the `<ul>`, but since someone else installed the plugin, I figured I would just target the relevant menu that already exists, this way easier to maintain just the css.